# Magento 2 - Top link position

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, toplinks

I was working with the layout xml for the top links. My code is in my custom module default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="storelocator-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title Link</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link-uri</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Now I can get my link in top.links area. But it shows at the beginning. I like to move it at the end... But I can't able to move it. 
Can anyone help me to fix its position to the end..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this it helps you if it work accept the answer it help others

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
  <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link-new"  after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="storelocator-link" after="register-link-new">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title Link</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link-uri</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>


</body>
```

Comment: Such approach may break other modules (e.g. other extensions), which rely on `register-link` block.

Comment: @Alex:- in complete project no where it used

Comment: @PradeepKumar merchant can install another extension in the future, which may use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your module after the module(s)that place the other links, I mean as dependecie of the other(s) module(s).

Comment: Other links I have like "Sign in" and "Create an account" which is dependent on the customer module so that I have done my squence in my custom module: module.xml
<sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Store"/>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
But still it not go to the end...

Comment: Ok, another try... can you check the markup on page source (if perhaps link are _right floating_ you will see them in reverse order). Another possible workaround would be search for some after/before flag in layout.